# What's Scar's name?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-manga

Before the manga ended, I remember reading somewhere that part of the things that should be revealed by the end was Scar's name, but I don't recall ever finding it out. What's Scar's name, was it ever revealed?

Comment: That's easy, it's [Jugenmusugenmegogonosedegakaisadasensugesugematsufuraimatsufuraimatsukurunatokorosuruntorayamagojiburagojibaibobaibonoshoringashoringgagurindaigurindainobumbokobinnobumbokonanojoukyuumenochousuke.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8_NzBdtQjI)

Answer (score 12):

His name was never revealed.

According to [this](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Scar):

> In the first anime, Scar died without his name ever being revealed. However, the author planned to reveal Scar's name before the manga finishes (in the "extras" at the end of volume 15, Arakawa states she has a name for Scar, but it's a secret). In chapter 102, when Wrath asks Scar what his name is, Scar replies he has no name and abandoned it long ago. As of Chapter 108, Scar officially has no name, stating that after dying twice, he no longer exists. It is unknown if his name will ever be revealed.

Comment: As a joke in the non-canon 4-Koma Theater, it is stated that Scar's real name is Jugemu-jugemu Gokōnosurikire Kaijarisuigyo-no Suigyōmatsu Unraimatsu Fūraimatsu Kūnerutokoroni-sumutokoro Yaburakōjino-burakōji Paipopaipo-paiponoshūringan Shūringanno-gūrindai Gūrindaino-ponpokopīno-ponpokonāno Chōkyūmeino-chōsuke, derived from the Japanese folktale "Jugemu." The joke also states that King Bradley, another character whose real name is unknown, shares the same name.

Comment: @Dimitrimx I don't fully understand but some parts means like "without a place to live" or so it seems. **What would be the translation for that?**

Comment: @Prix (I aint japanese so this is a rough translation) live long, live long and prosper. may great wealth await you whenever you go, even in different lands and under different skies. like the long lived king shuringan. and his dear wife furindai . and their childeren ponpokopi and ponpokona. live a long and blessed life.

Comment: @Dimitrimx Not quite: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jugemu